# does Trie*& and Trie** means Same?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

```cpp
class Trie
{
public:
    bool isLeaf;
    Trie* character[CHAR_SIZE];

    // Constructor
    Trie()
    {
        this->isLeaf = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < CHAR_SIZE; i++)
            this->character[i] = nullptr;
    }

    void insert(std::string);
    bool deletion(Trie*&, std::string);
    bool search(std::string);
    bool haveChildren(Trie const*);
};
```

In here does Trie*& and Trie** means Same?

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not the same. `Trie*&` is a reference to a (Trie-)pointer, `Trie**` is a pointer to a (Trie-)pointer. To illustrate the difference, consider this:

```
void test_a(int*& refToPtr)
{
    refToPtr = new int();
    *refToPtr = 123;
}
```

To achieve the same using `int**`, your function would look like:

```
void test_b(int** ptrToPtr)
{
    *ptrToPtr = new int();
    **ptrToPtr = 123;
}
```

One difference to keep in mind is that you can locally change `ptrToPtr` (so you can change to which pointer variable `ptrToPtr` points). With `refToPtr` being a reference, it is impossible to locally change to which pointer variable `refToPtr` refers.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not the same.

> In here does Trie*& and Trie** means Same?

- `Trie*&`: is a reference to pointer.
- `Trie**`: is pointer to pointer.

For more information, you can take a look at

- [What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in#:%7E:text=A%20pointer%20is%20just%20a,as%20the%20variable%20it%20references.&text=A%20pointer%20can%20be%20assigned%20nullptr%20directly%2C%20whereas%20reference%20cannot.)
- [Tutorial on tutorialspoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_references.htm#:%7E:text=A%20reference%20variable%20is%20an,to%20refer%20to%20the%20variable)